# Boostrap 4; Can't fit 4 simple columns on full width

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need to have 4 tables with fix width displayed on the full width when on a large screen, and underneath each other when on a small screen (mobile). 
With below code I can't even have it working on full width (column 4 does not fit on screen while there is space enough).
Here my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title></title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Mono">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="margin-top: 70px;" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <table style="width: 100px">
                    <tr>Table 1</tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <table style="width: 100px">
                    <tr>Table 2</tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <table style="width: 100px">
                    <tr>Table 3</tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <table style="width: 100px">
                    <tr>Table 4</tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It worked fine on my jsFiddle. Also is there a reason why you missed all table `<tbody>` and `<td>`?

Comment: GOOD LESSON LEARNEDMy original Bootstrap css file was somehow altered (it resides on my server), and all went fine after having replaced it with a fresh one.
Conclusion: on strange behaviors, just try to temporarily replace your css file……
(<tbody> and <td> were omitted here due to laziness….)